# Angular Google Maps loading issue

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am using angular google map for displaying locations. The latitude and longitude are served from an api. If the response size is large(15000 min.), the map takes time to display all the locations. I have a few questions regarding this issue-

1. Is this a drawback of the map that it cannot render large sizes of data in a short time?
2. Is there any way to improve this performance? If not, what solutions should I follow? Should I think of using a new library?

I have tried using small chunks of data to load by sequential call, but assembling all the data takes a lot of time as the dataset is large.